# how to make professional back button in action bar

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I made back button by using activity parent and getactionsupport just like this:

```
<activity 
    android:name=".News_details"
    android:parentActivityName=".Main2Activity" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.package.Main2Activity" />
</activity>
```

I also add this to my activity in the manifest.

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

so what the result that I get ?

[image]

The blue arrow displays properly when I run my app in android version 4.+.  When I use android version 5.+ the blue arrow reveres direction.

Comment: That is weird. Try updating the support library. Maybe there is a bug. Otherwise you could just add your own icon. But that should not be necessary

Comment: @JemilRiahi sir how can i add the icon ?

Comment: getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.icon); Try this

Comment: @JemilRiahi same issue

Comment: Could you post the activitiy's code (The one that is showing the wrong icon)

Comment: in whole app its keep showing same issue

Comment: ok weird. Could you post the gradle file with the imports?

Comment: WHat's your locale?  Are you in a right to left language?

Comment: @GabeSechan  right

Comment: @humam If you're in a right to left language, that would be expected.  THe arrow will reverse, because the idea of a "back" direction goes the other way.  Your layout needs to anticipate this and move it to the other side.  That's why "start" and "end" gravities and layout parameters exist.  If you're on an old version of ANdroid that may not work, good RTL support only came in 17 or so.

Comment: i make it rtl false and the issue apeear in android 4.+ when i make it true the issue apeear in android 5.+ :/ @GabeSechan